# Not able to send messages from server to client via Netty

Tags: java, netty, nio

I am just getting started with `Netty`, so please bear with me if this sounds really stupid.

What I am trying to accomplish is ask the server to send a ping message to the client upon successful connection to a client. For that I have overridden the `channelActive` method of the `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` class. When the client connects to the server, I can see the "client connected" being printed, but somehow the server does not send the message to the client. I guess I am doing something really wrong here. Can anyone please help me out?

Here's the code snippet in the server-

```
public class ChatServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        System.out.println("client connected");
        String msg = "ping";
        final ChannelFuture f = ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
        f.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                if(future.isSuccess()) {
                    System.out.println("Wrote message on active");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Client code -

```
public class ChatClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        System.out.println("Msg: " + (String)msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
        System.out.println("Exception...closing channel");
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

The problem is I don't see the message being printed out in the client upon `channelRead()`, so I am assuming the server hasn't sent the message to the client.

Please let me know if you need any other part of the code too. I'm using Netty 4.0.21.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to send a ByteBuf to have the data sent out, Typically in the pipeline near the start of the pipeline will be an encoder which is responsible for taking your message and turning it into a ByteBuf to send onto the network.

Have a look at the Write a time server section of the netty user guide; http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html

Here they wrap a time value into the ByteBuf.
For your example you'll want to try;

```
String msg = "ping";
final ByteBuf byteBufMsg = ctx.alloc().buffer(msg.length());
byteBufMsg.writeBytes(msg.getBytes());
ctx.writeAndFlush(byteBufMsg);
```

As mentioned by Norman in the comments, you can also add a [StringEncoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/string/StringEncoder.html) to the pipeline. This is particularly nice as it also has a [StringDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/string/StringDecoder.html) which compliments it on the client side. Adding these before your ChatServerHandler will allow you to keep your class as is in the example.

Your pipeline setup would look something like (From [StringEncoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/string/StringEncoder.html) example);

```
// Encoder
pipeline.addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
pipeline.addLast("chatServer", new ChatServerHandler());
```

And on your client pipeline;

```
// Decoders
pipeline.addLast("frameDecoder", new LineBasedFrameDecoder(80)); //This terminates strings on line endings, ie \n
pipeline.addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
pipeline.addLast("chatClient", new ChatClientHandler());
```

And update msg to being;
    String msg = "ping\n";
As it needs the line ending so [LineBasedFrameDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LineBasedFrameDecoder.html) will read the message out correctly.

Other available encoders can be see from the [MessageToMessageEncoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/MessageToMessageEncoder.html) subclasses list, as well as the [MessageToMessageDecoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/MessageToMessageDecoder.html) for available decoders.

Comment: Alternative you can also add a StringEncoder to the ChannelPipeline that will handle the encoding from String -> ByteBuf for you.

Comment: Thanks for that piece @NormanMaurer! 

Do you know if is there anything the user guide that outlines some of the available encoders? Had a look through didn't see anything that jumped out, other than using [MessageToByteEncoder](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#wiki-h3-15).

More info available at [StringEncoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/string/StringEncoder.html) for it's usage.  Other encoders can be seen from the subclasses for [MessageToMessageEncoder](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/MessageToMessageEncoder.html)

Comment: Thanks @NormanMaurer for your input and Doswell for an updated answer, extremely useful.